# How to convert a query string into a collection of objects? Ideally using model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding

I'm trying to take a query string that is passed in (as a string) and convert it into a collection of objects so I can call a method using reflection using those parsed objects as the parameters. We used to  fire a webrequest from inside that code to the action which then handled the model binding but for a whole bunch of reasons we are trying to get away from that system.

Is there a way that I can use the model binder to convert the query string into a collection of objects? I already am using reflection to get the method parameters I just need some way to convert them.

Comment: Is your query string xml or json?  You're trying to deserialize it in the code behind?

Comment: It's in the regular(?) format. eg: "?parameter1=12/22/2014&param2=blahstringblah&param3=[complex object string that model binder handles]"

Comment: Why not implement your own model binder?

Comment: @Christian I assume you mean just build my own method to transform strings into their respective objects? I already have some of the model binders I just can't figure out how to use them outside of the magic that converts query strings to objects when you call an action.

I could create my own parsing method but we already have a lot of logic in our own custom model binders that I'd rather leave alone and leverage there.